# How do you use a boolean to define a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables

i want to define a variable using javascript for my pac-man, (https://github.com/JavascriptCoder999/pac-man256)

i tried...

```
var myVariable=0;
if(//myVariable is 0){
//definition
}
```

could be false or true if "0" doesn't work
you could use a for loop though

Comment: We need some more information; it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you can't define a boolean variable you're going to have a real tough time with the rest of that assignment.

Comment: Best of luck with your assignment!!

Comment: @TemporaryFix yes,right now i'm working on the ghosts

Comment: @user1599011 i am basically trying to use a true or false to say what a variable does for my pac-man game (https://github.com/JavascriptCoder999)

Comment: Have you tried `if(myVariable === 0){...}`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myVariable = myVariable ? myVariable : "someValue"
// Will be set to "someValue"
// if not initialized, 0 , -0, "", false, null or undefined
```